What are the tradeoffs to be considered when choosing solar panel system and electrical equipment voltages for a future base on the Moon?
It's a good idea to choose a standard, but since it's the Moon, do we need to consider the effects of some of the Moon's extreme environmental conditions and the physical limitations of devices such as rad-hard switches

Given the ease of obtaining ac-dc, dc-ac, ac-ac, and dc-dc converters, why does it matter?

@JonCuster Just for example, scarcity of copper for wire, and challenges with aluminum wire might suggest that higher voltages/lower currents might be preferred for power distribution on a lunar base.

@uhoh - sure, but that has nothing to do with the photovoltaic voltage. Or other applications. The guts of your computer don’t run on line voltage, etc.

I appreciate the advice, the question and body do appear to be inconsistent, and I think your explanation is more acceptable to the respondent@
uhoh

Certainly some potential to this question. See: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20230008453/downloads/IAPG_Charts_small_Davies_06282023.pdf.
